# how to rotate image to it's normal orientation before move in php

Tags: php

Hello i'm getting some picture from my app and some of picture are rotated i want to store them with normal orientation  before or after move them (don't know which one is better) what i'm trying right now is to use

```
  $rotate = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);
            imagepng($rotate,$file_path);
```

but it will rotate all the pictures . so i will really be greatful for any help or comment this is my full code ty

```
    public function insertImages($pic_files,$pic_numbers,$sg_id){
         $check_insert_number = 0 ;
         $upload_path = '../uploads/sg/';
          $upload_path_fake = 'uploads/sg/';
          $server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());
          $upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/keepwords/'.$upload_path_fake;

            foreach($pic_files as $key => $value) {

            $fileinfo = pathinfo($value['name']);
            $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];
            $image_name_temp = pathinfo($value['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $image_name = time()."_".$image_name_temp;

            $file_url = $upload_url . $image_name . '.' . $extension;
            $file_path = $upload_path . $image_name . '.'. $extension;


             try{

                move_uploaded_file($value['tmp_name'],$file_path);
                $source = imagecreatefrompng($file_path);
                $rotate = imagerotate($source, 90, 0);
                imagepng($rotate,$file_path);

           $stmt=$this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO sg_image(url,sg_id) values (?,?)");
          $stmt->bind_param("si",$file_url,$sg_id);
          $result=$stmt->execute();
              if($result){


             $check_insert_number++;
             } else {


             }

           }catch(Exception $e){
          die($e->getMessage());

                }           

         }
         if($check_insert_number==$pic_numbers) {
             return 1 ;

         }else {
             return 0 ;

         }   
}
```